# How can i create index on specific property using Nest in Elastic Search?

Tags: c#, .net, nest

I want to make ID column as index able in Elastic Search with Nest Client.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
[ElasticType(IdProperty = "Id", Name = "person")]    
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I was able to do it with below approach.
  [ElasticsearchType(Name = "person")]
    public class Person
    {
        [Text(Index = true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Text(Index = true)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Text(Index = false)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }